# jQuery / Javascript - else if statement not reaching else if

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm relatively new to jQuery / javascript but I've come across what looks like a simple snag to solve, and I just can't see what's wrong. Sorry if this ends up being simple but I've searched loads but to no end.

I'm trying to get various divs to fade in or out depending on whether they are 'visible' or not. The divs are effectively 'pages' that I want to advance when the 'next' arrow is clicked.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $("#page1 > div").hide();
   $("#page2 > div").hide();
   $("#page3 > div").hide();

   $("#page1 > div").fadeIn(800);

   $("#NextArrow").click(function(){
      if($("#page1").is(":visible")){
         $("#page1 > div").fadeOut(800);
         $("#page2 > div").fadeIn(800);
      }
      else if($("#page2").is(":visible")){
         $("#page2 > div").fadeOut(800);
         $("#page3 > div").fadeIn(800);
      }
      else {
         alert("no page");
      }
   })
})
```

Here is the html:

```
<table id="MainTable" width="765" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="min-height:400px; padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px">
            <div id="page1" style="position:absolute">
                <div id="p1Title">Introduction</div>
                <p></p>
                <div id="p1Detail">....detail.....</div>
            </div>
            <div id="page2" style="position:absolute">
                <div id="p2Title">Introduction - continued</div>
                <p></p>
                <div id="p2Detail">....detail.....</div>
            </div>
            <div id="page3" style="position:absolute">
                <div id="p3Title">Members</div>
                <p></p>
                <div id="p3Detail">....detail.....</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <div id="NextArrow"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the css for "NextArrow":

```
#NextArrow
{
  width:120px;
  height:34px;
  background-image:url('NextArrow.gif');
}

#NextArrow:hover
{
  background-image:url('NextArrowHover.gif');
}
```

So here's the problem. When I click the 'NextArrow' div it fades 'page1' div out as expected and fades in 'page2' div. However, when I click it again nothing happens, not even getting the 'no page' alert.

Comment: With the way the code is working, it might be a simple case that you're just click the #nextarrow to fast for the animation, and it triggering before it's finished the last animation

Comment: That's not the problem, I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CKkpC/

Comment: Looking at the docs, it actually states `Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible`. So all your div's at the start are considered visible

Comment: Which browser are you using?  If Chrome or Firefox are there any errors firing in the inspector/firebug when you click?

Comment: Put alerts in to the other two code blocks. I'd wager the above is correct and you're hitting code block #1 each time.

Comment: How many pages do you plan on having because your code is going to become huge if you have more to come. The better solution is to create a function that looks at the page and then determines what page to hide. Cause at this rate my friend your code will end up being huge.

Comment: @Cam : I'm only thinking of about 7 ot 8 pages so the code is unlikely to get too bulky. I appreciate it would be more efficient though to look at the page. If I end up with too many pages then I'll have to revisit this. Presumably there would be a way to use 'next' if I could get this to ignore child elements as all page div elements are on the same level?

Comment: If it comes to that, take a look at how jQuery Ui creates tabs for you, I built a project that counts how many LI's there are, and I set a fixed width for the LI's, so it would count the LI's, multiply it by the fixed width, and divide it by clicks to create x next button clicks and y previous button clicks. Crazy I know, but you could add 100 photos and it worked like a charm. If you need help with that let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is a trivial logical issue. `fadeOut` fades out the element - not its parent. The `:visible` check checks for the state of the container you specified - not its parent.

You are fading out `#page1 > div` and not `#page1`. As such, while empty, your `#page1` is still visible. As such, `$('#page1').is(':visible')` is always true regardless of the state of your page.

Consider changing the fadeout/fadein calls to fade the page IDs and not their containing divs.

Comment: ok, this seems to be the case. I've therefore adjusted my jquery to include the #page element as well as the '#page > div' elements for each fadeIn and fadeOut. Very quick responses by the way. This was my first time using it and I thought I'd have to wait hours. Very impressed!

Comment: @sr28: Based on the difficulty of your question, answers might take a while. However, it's always better to have more than one person try to fix something. Also, hiding a container also hides all elements that inherit opacity without marking them as invisible. So you only need to hide page1, not the divs. Makes your life easier. Anytime! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're checking if `#page1` is visible, and if it is, you're fading out the `<div>` elements *inside* it, which won't make `#page1` invisible.

Try this instead:

```
if($("#page1").is(":visible")){
    $("#page1").fadeOut(800);
    $("#page2").fadeIn(800);
}
```